# Унифицировать предложение о регистрации

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, регистрация

Если попробовать добавить в избранное незарегистрированным пользователем на мете, то:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если попробовать проголосовать за вопрос, то:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можем мы как-то это унифицировать и привести к одному виду?

Comment: Скорее всего это надо предлагать разбарам. На enSO тоже самое.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324516/260198